# SimpleAddress from PropertyUrl

Tags: c#, episerver

1. I have certain page having both long (Page1/Page2/MyPage) and **simple** (MyPage) addresses.
2. Then I want to reference it in certain place via PropertyUrl:

   ```
   [CultureSpecific]
   [Required]
   [BackingType(typeof(PropertyUrl))]
   [Display(
       Name = "Link",
       Description = "Link to the page",
       GroupName = SystemTabNames.Content,
       Order = 1)]
   public virtual Url Link { get; set; }
   ```
3. I want the **simple** address (if it exists) to be used for the routing or url rendering but not the long one.

I am looking for some elegant solution for it if it exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got an [answer from Brad McDavid](http://world.episerver.com/forum/developer-forum/Developer-to-developer/Thread-Container/2017/1/simpleaddress-from-propertyurl-/?pageIndex=1#reply)

Modified it a bit to fit better to my task:

```
public static string GetExternalUrl(this Url url)
{
    var content = UrlResolver.Service.Route(new UrlBuilder(url));

    return GetExternalUrl(content);
}

public static string GetExternalUrl(this ContentReference contentReference)
{
    if (ContentReference.IsNullOrEmpty(contentReference)) return null;

    var content = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IContentLoader>().Get<IContent>(contentReference);

    return GetExternalUrl(content);
}

public static string GetExternalUrl(this IContent content)
{
    var externalProperty = content?.Property["PageExternalURL"];

    return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(externalProperty?.ToString()) ? $"/{externalProperty.ToString().Trim('/')}/" : null;
}
```